# Process has active assertions beyond permitted time iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, background

I have an app built with Cordova and it has some tasks in background. The problem is I get random crashes and I'm not able to figure out what it's wrong.

I get the next exception :

```
Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  2

Application Specific Information:
<BKNewProcess: 0x1758f950; com.app; pid: 2675; hostpid: -1> has active assertions beyond permitted time: 
{(
    <BKProcessAssertion: 0x17692970> id: 2675-CA057A50-06BF-4BA1-9F0C-7641112B945E name: Called by MyApp, from unknown method process: <BKNewProcess: 0x1758f950; gbi.cro; pid: 2675; hostpid: -1> permittedBackgroundDuration: 180.000000 reason: finishTask owner pid:2675 preventSuspend  preventIdleSleep  preventSuspendOnSleep ,
    <BKProcessAssertion: 0x17697c30> id: 2675-A03FFC10-1D0A-4BDC-BF64-61358346530E name: Called by MyApp, from unknown method process: <BKNewProcess: 0x1758f950; gbi.cro; pid: 2675; hostpid: -1> permittedBackgroundDuration: 180.000000 reason: finishTask owner pid:2675 preventSuspend  preventIdleSleep  preventSuspendOnSleep 
)}
```

And the thread 2 is:

```
Thread 2 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x30ae3518 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x30ae330c mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x227d1596 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 142
3   CoreFoundation                  0x227cfb5c __CFRunLoopRun + 1012
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2271cb2c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2271c93e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   CFNetwork                       0x222d178a +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 482
7   Foundation                      0x2351e996 __NSThread__main__ + 1114
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x30b75e64 _pthread_body + 136
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x30b75dd6 _pthread_start + 114
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x30b73b80 thread_start + 4
```

I've the whole trace but it's so big, so if someone needs some information, let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried to track them with breakpoints ?

Comment: hi, the problem is that the crash is random, maybe I get it after 10 min...after 5 hours...so I can't debug it with breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is annoying which is hard to debug by breakpoints, I suggest you try some trick when the app resigns active in the following approach, to apply for more time from system:

```
__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundTaskIdentifier = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:backgroundTaskIdentifier];
    backgroundTaskIdentifier = backgroundTaskIdentifier;
}];
```

Also, have a look on Apple:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html